# Have html show up after javascript function completes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to create a generic game of blackjack through javascript. The game starts when you click the start button:

```
<button type="button" onClick="deal()">Start Game</button>
```

which in turn runs the method deal:

```
function deal() {  
    card1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);  
    card2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);  
    card1 = changeCard(card1);  
    card2 = changeCard(card2);  
    score = card1 + card2;  
    for (var i = 0; i < aceAmount || score > 21;aceAmount--) {  
        score -= 10;  
    }  
    document.write("You were dealt a " + card1 + " and a " + card2 + " for a total of " + score + ".\nDo you wish to hit or pass?");  
    aceAmount = 0;  
};
```

My question is once the deal method runs, how can I get two html buttons to show up on the screen, such as:

```
<button type="button" onClick="hit()">Hit</button>  
<button type="button" onClick="pass()">Pass</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to do?
Use the CSS [`display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS%3adisplay) to hide your buttons, then using the [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById), method you "select" those buttons to do some "Javascripty" stuff on them.

Your HTML

```
<button id="hit_btn" style="display:none;" type="button" onClick="hit()">Hit</button>  
<button id="pass_btn" style="display:none;" type="button" onClick="pass()">Pass</button>
```

and add this to your Javascript function:

```
document.getElementById('hit_btn').style.display = '';
document.getElementById('pass_btn').style.display = '';
```

and when you want to hide them back again

```
document.getElementById('hit_btn').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('pass_btn').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

you could set an id or class on the buttons, and set a css rule with display:none. At the end of the deal function, set a line which changes display to block or inline. in jQuery, it would be

```
$('button.hit').css({visibility: "visible"})
```